# Why are these strings not equivalent in MySQL but equivalent in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to migrate an application database from MySQL to SQL Server using the vendor's conversion tool. When I do, I get a unique constraint violation error that indicates I'm trying to write a value ("Canon Inc.") twice in one column of the SQL Server table.

I logged into the live system (MySQL) and ran the query below, shown with its results (zero records). This tells me that MySQL doesn't see any records where the column contains duplicate values.

[image: Screenshot showing no duplicate values in NAME column of SoftwareManufacturer table]

However, when I search more generally for Canon Inc., I do indeed find two records. But when I check the character & bit lengths of the strings, they're clearly not *exactly* the same, as shown here:

[image: Screenshot showing two records for Canon Inc. with different bit and character lengths]

What could the difference be between these two strings? Is there a way for me to clean this up?

Comment: Don't post pictures, post code

Comment: spaces, you are doing a direct check (group by) and in the second instance you are doing a like (%) so the spaces on the end are being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have a trailing space on the second canon inc. That would account for the character length being one more than the other one, and I'd bet that SQL Server is ignoring the trailing space.